# Can PHP be used to redirect

Tags: php, html

I have a very noobish PHP question so please bear with me...

How would I use PHP to redirect a user to a specific page based on their input via a form?

For example, if they input that they are from Michigan than the script would redirect them to www.site.com/michigan.php.

Answer (score 5):

```
header("Location: http://example.com/");
exit;
```

Comment: would the condtional look something like this: if ($state == 'michigan') { header('Location: http://www.site.com/michigan.php'); } ?

Comment: @charles.redmond. If $state really hold the state name then almost.. it's **really important** to have the exit statement after your header() call, otherwise it will redirect but it will also run the rest of the php script

Comment: @Ben Thank's for the extra input! I wouldn't want that happening :-o

Comment: @charles.redmond - Avoid hardcoding when possible.  If this is the approach you proceed, then use a variable to retrieve the selected state and then dynamically redirect the user to the corresponding page based off of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
//assuming the data is from post
$from = $_POST['state']; // say Michigan
header("Location: http://www.site.com/{$from}.php");
exit;
```

Comment: If thats wat you need then could you Accept the answer.. :)

Comment: You may want to sanitize the input before using it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect like so. You can choose to sub-in variables in the url to make it state-by-state.

```
header('Location: www.site.com/michigan.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

the man pages are your friend!

header() is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the » HTTP/1.1 specification for more information on HTTP headers.

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Comment: I checked the manual but it didn't make to much sense. I've only been using PHP for about 3 weeks :-\

Comment: yeah, it's tough starting out, but worth the effort!  Good luck! it gets easier

Answer (score 0):

`http_redirect` alse could be helpfull, http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//To redirect page of another site
header('Location:http://www.redirectTosite.com/');
?>

<?php
To redirect to anothe rpage of your website
header('Location:/yourPage.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have completed a database query, you should redirect the page so that the form data don't get resubmitted in you press F5 and there will be a duplicate entry in database

so after and insert update or delete redirect the page.

```
 <?php
header('Location:test.php');
?>
```